# Сделать перенаправление httaccess по маске

Tags: регулярные-выражения, веб-программирование

Как сделать перенаправление `httaccess` по маске

с этого

```
/component/jak2filter/?Itemid=&issearch=1&theme=faq&category_id=1&xf_8[0]=3
```

на вот это

```
?issearch=1&theme=faq&isc=1&ordering=order&category_id=1&xf_8[0]=3
```

вот эта часть динамическая `&category_id=1&xf_8[0]=3` в обоих случаях

Answer (score -1):

это же вроде обычный гет запрос не? $_GET['category_id'] берет его значения. Потом обрабатываешь это все и делаешь перенаправление.